# How to make a treeview from a database column filepath

Tags: c#, treeview

I have a column in a database table which contains the filepath for each file in the table. How can I make a treeview in c# which will mimic the filepath column in my database.

Here is what a sample filepath column looks like in the column:

```
jsmith/project1/hello.cs
jsmith/project1/what.cs
jwilliams/project2/hello.cs
```

Comment: Can you please add how the tree view should look like.

Comment: Why the downvote?  I don't think its a bad question...  The submitter didn't provide what the tree view should look like because it should be fairly obvious :)

Comment: Can we assume, as Javier Morillo did in his answer below, that you'll have access to the "raw data" in the column as a List<string> : if not, what format would the "raw data" be in ? Can we assume the "raw data" is alpha-sorted as suggested in your example ? Finally, can we assume that the "depth" of any filepath is arbitrarily deep : or, as in your example, each filepath has fixed depth of #3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a little example. I've test it and it works fine.

**Note that** I've made a class MyDataBase to simulate your database:

```
public void CreateTreeView()
{
    TreeView myTreeview = new TreeView();
    myTreeview.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.Controls.Add(myTreeview);

    foreach (string field in MyDataBase.FieldsInMyColumn())
    {
        string[] elements = field.Split('/');
        TreeNode parentNode = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < elements.Length - 1; ++i)
        {                                        
            if (parentNode == null)
            {
                bool exits = false;
                foreach (TreeNode node in myTreeview.Nodes)
                {
                    if (node.Text == elements[i])
                    {
                        exits = true;
                        parentNode = node;   
                    }
                }

                if (!exits)
                {
                    TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode(elements[i]);
                    myTreeview.Nodes.Add(childNode);
                    parentNode = childNode;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                bool exits = false;
                foreach (TreeNode node in parentNode.Nodes)
                {
                    if (node.Text == elements[i])
                    {
                        exits = true;
                        parentNode = node;
                    }
                }

                if (!exits)
                {
                    TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode(elements[i]);
                    parentNode.Nodes.Add(childNode);
                    parentNode = childNode;
                }
            }
        }

        if (parentNode != null)
        {
           parentNode.Nodes.Add(elements[elements.Length - 1]);
        }
    }         
}
```

**EDIT**

Here I paste my auxiliar code, that you don´t need, but it will help you to understand my code, or to copy/paste and try it by yourself.

```
public static class MyDataBase
{
    private static List<string> fields = new List<string>();

    public static void AddField(string field)
    {
        fields.Add(field);
    }

    public static IList<string> FieldsInMyColumn()
    {
        return fields;
    }
}
```

**Constructor in form1**

```
public Form1()
{

    InitializeComponent();

    MyDataBase.AddField("jsmith/project1/hello.cs");
    MyDataBase.AddField("jsmith/project1/what.cs");
    MyDataBase.AddField("jsmith/project2/hello.cs");

    CreateTreeView();
}
```