# Expand TreeViewItems in wpf fast

Tags: wpf, performance, treeview, treeviewitem

I know how to expand all nodes from a treeview:

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="TreeViewItem.IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
            </Style>
 </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

the only problem is that it takes about a minute to expand all nodes... that's probably because there are so many items. How could I speed up this process?

---

Edit:

So I have a list:  `List<ScanItems> MyFilesList`

`ScanItem` is a class that has properties such as: FullName, Name, Size, DateCreated, ComparePath and other specific properties that I need that's why I did not used the FileInfo class.

`ScanFile` is a class that inherits from ScanItems so it is just like it with the addition of other custom properties.

`ScanDir` is another class that inherits also from ScanItem and it has the following property:

```
public List<ScanItem> items{get;set;}
```

the reason why I have included that property is so that I can have another list withing an item.

Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415037/populate-treeview-from-list-of-file-paths-in-wpf/6560891#6560891) regarding how to populate a treeview from a list of files.

so now I hope I explain my self correctly on how I am binding that list to the treeview.

Now let me explain how I added the files to MyFilesList.  I created a recursion method to look for files in a directory. If the curent directory contained a file then add a ScanFile item. If it contained a Folder then add a ScanDir object and call the same method again passing the list of ScanDir. So this process takes about 8 seconds to scan my external hard drive. after that method get executed my list may contain just 4 items but one of those items will contain a list of maybe 20 items and so forth just like a folder may have 5 items and if one of those 5 items happens to be a folder that folder can have additional items.

So when I execute TreeView.DataContext = MyFilesList the treeview gets populated in less than a second. But when I include:

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="TreeViewItem.IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
            </Style>
 </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

that style inside the treeview the treeview takes to long to load.

Comment: How many are we talking about? If you're showing data from a database using Linq then maybe have a look what is your linq doing - maybe you're hitting the database for each record separately.

Comment: The list<T> is binded to the treeview. the treeview consist of about 60,000 items. When I exclude the style from the project it does not take time to load.

Comment: So that is a lot but how are you retrieving the items from the database? The code would be good. If you're using linq with a navigation property "Child" (or similar) then when you're expanding a node then most probably you're hitting the database for it... about 60k times

Comment: Hyp thanks a lot for the help you are right I am not being clear how I populated my list. Take a look at my edit. I am working on it now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the posts made by [Bea Stollnitz](https://github.com/bstollnitz/old-wpf-blog) about treeviews and performance.
Relevant post would be:

- How can I expand items in a TreeView? [Part I](https://github.com/bstollnitz/old-wpf-blog/tree/master/47-ExpandTreeViewPart1) / [Part II](https://github.com/bstollnitz/old-wpf-blog/tree/master/48-ExpandTreeViewPart2) / [Part III](https://github.com/bstollnitz/old-wpf-blog/tree/master/49-ExpandTreeViewPart3)
- Are there any tricks that will help me improve TreeView’s performance? [Part I](https://github.com/bstollnitz/old-wpf-blog/tree/master/39-TreeViewPerformancePart1) / [Part II](https://github.com/bstollnitz/old-wpf-blog/tree/master/40-TreeViewPerformancePart2) / [Part III](https://github.com/bstollnitz/old-wpf-blog/tree/master/41-TreeViewPerformancePart3)

She does a good job explaining in detail all of the options you can try out. Too much content to put it all here.

Comment: [Part I](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/475) / [Part II](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/477) / [Part III](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/480)

Comment: All of these links are dead now. :(

Comment: @AriRoth I've corrected links in the accepted answer if case you (or somebody else) will need this info.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried looping through the treeviewitems and expanding them "manually" by setting

```
IsExpanded = true;
```

If that doesn't work then try a work around and add to your `ScanDir` ( I presume that's the only class which you expand? ) a property `IsExpanded` (or similar) and bind to it in your template. Not the best of solutions practise wise but if it would work...