# HierarchicalDataTemplate with Treeview in MVVM

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I'm relatively new to MVVM and WPF. I'm attempting to fill a TreeView control with a directory and it's files / subdirectories (in effect the contents of a zip file that I have unpacked)

Following along after this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415037/populate-treeview-from-list-of-file-paths-in-wpf), I have the following class:

```
namespace IFR_Full.Model
{
    public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
    }

    public class FileItem : Item
    {
    }

    public class DirectoryItem : Item
    {
        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

        public DirectoryItem()
        {
            Items = new List<Item>();
        }
    }

    public class TVItemProvider
    {
        public List<Item> GetItems(string path)
        {
            var items = new List<Item>();
            var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);

            foreach (var directory in dirInfo.GetDirectories())
            {
                var item = new DirectoryItem
                    {
                        Name = directory.Name,
                        Path = directory.FullName,
                        Items = GetItems(directory.FullName)
                    };
                items.Add(item);
            }

            foreach (var file in dirInfo.GetFiles())
            {
                var item = new FileItem
                {
                    Name = file.Name,
                    Path = file.FullName
                };
                items.Add(item);
            }
            return items;
        }
    }
}
```

In my ViewModel class I have these properties:

```
TVItemProvider TVIP = new TVItemProvider();

private List<Item> _tvitems;
public List<Item> TVItems
{
    get { return _tvitems; }
}
```

which is created in this method:

```
private void LoadIDMLTreeView(string path)
{
    _tvitems = TVIP.GetItems(path);
}
```

I set the header and DataContext of my MainWindow like this:

```
...
xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:IFR_Full"
xmlns:Model ="clr-namespace:IFR_Full.Model"
...

<Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:ExcelImportViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

and set my treeview xaml code like this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="IDMLView" Margin="10,171.74,10,8" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Model:DirectoryItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TVItems}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Path}" />                  
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate> 
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Model:FileItem}">
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Path}" />
    </DataTemplate>             
 </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

When I run the program in debug mode I can see that TVItems contains the appropriate items (Directories and files), but my TreeView control is blank.

I imagine that the issue is with the bindings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Change `<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding}" ...` to `<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TVItems}" ...`
- Also , Change to `<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DirectoryItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >`
- Your class has to be like this :

  ```
   public class TVItemProvider
      {

          List<object> items = new List<object>();
            DirectoryInfo dirInfo;
            public List<object> GetItems(string path)
          {
              dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
              foreach (var directory in dirInfo.GetDirectories())
              {
                  var item = new DirectoryItem
                  {
                      Name = directory.Name,
                      Path = directory.FullName,
                      Items = new TVItemProvider().GetItems(directory.FullName)
                  };
                  items.Add(item);
              }

              foreach (var file in dirInfo.GetFiles())
              {
                  var item = new FileItem
                  {
                      Name = file.Name,
                      Path = file.FullName
                  };

                  items.Add(item);
              }
              return items;
          }
  ```

  }
- Finally change the type of your lists to `List<object>` (all of them)

  Hope it would help

Comment: When I make this change the treeview fills with only the top-level items.  I am expecting a tree structure: the DirectoryItems have FileItem subs.

Comment: Excellent HichemC!  That worked... now I need to study the answer to understand what you did!