# Making a Databound Treeview with a list of strings

Tags: c#, treeview

I have a list with strings which i would like to turn into a Tree view.
The strings are the folder names of ones (exchange) Inbox. The strings would look like this

```
string a "Username\Inbox"
string b "Username\Inbox\Subfolder"
string c "Username\inbox\subfolder"
string d "Username\Createdfolder"
string e "Username\Createdfolder\subfolder"
```

I have all those strings in a list and would like to turn it into a treeview.
I have read i could turn it all into XML and it would be able to load it.
But to be honest i dont know where to start to make this into xml so i can bind it to a treeview.
Ofcourse if there is a better way to bind them please tell me.

Comment: Google is your friend: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155977/populate-treeview-from-a-list-of-path , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253232/how-to-populate-treeview-with-file-path-which-is-saved-in-database , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415037/populate-treeview-from-list-of-file-paths-in-wpf ,...

Comment: @Arie Ohh! Thanks for the link. the first link is EXACTLY what i was looking for. sorry for not finding it on my own!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this format:

```
  <nodes>
    <node name="a" value="Username\Inbox"/>
    <node name="b" value="Username\Inbox\Subfolder"/>
    <node name="c" value="Username\inbox\subfolder"/>
    <node name="d" value="Username\Createdfolder"/>
    <node name="e" value="Username\Createdfolder\subfolder"/>
  </nodes>
```

in c# put

```
        string xml =
        "<nodes>" +
            "<node name=\"a\" value=\"Username\\Inbox\"/>" +
            "<node name=\"b\" value=\"Username\\Inbox\\Subfolder\"/>" +
            "<node name=\"c\" value=\"Username\\inbox\\subfolder\"/>" +
            "<node name=\"d\" value=\"Username\\Createdfolder\"/>" +
            "<node name=\"e\" value=\"Username\\Createdfolder\\subfolder\"/>" +
        "</nodes>";
```

Comment: Thanks for showing how the format would have worked! i decided to follow one of the links Arie linked in the command since it seems easier, but thanks for the XML Example!.